# Extract Chinese text from Query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, cjk

I need to extract Chinese characters from the query string in an ASP.NET web application. 
When I tried it, I get "????" instead of the actual text. I know I need to decode it with  UTF-8 but its does not work. I have used:

```
String text = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["text"], System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

but I get "???" back from the operation.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two cases.

**1st Case** where your URL is real in chinese, the only function that get it is the **Request.RawUrl** (and not the Request.QueryString["text"]) From **Request.RawUrl** you need manually get your Chinese text from text=ελληνικασανκινεζικα.

**2nd Case** where you have first Encode your URL string before you send it. In this case the code I use is

```
String text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["text"]);
```

Hope this help.

**Note:** If you try to make test with Google Chrome, then what you type on url chrome is encode/decode automatically by browser and you are not see what actual you send. Try to use ie, for make your test.

Comment: I cant use case 2 as the request coming from the client browser is the first Request. So I am not setting the values in query string. 

I will try with case 1.

Comment: @A Junkie Remember that you need manual to get the text out... search for ? symbol, then for the TEXT= etc...

Comment: hi I see ??? in the Raw URL also.

"ClienteExterno.aspx?text=???&destinations=6981"

Comment: I got it. You need to install Chinese language pack and then use 

`String text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["text"]);' to extract the text. 

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Request.RawUrl