# URL Encoding for multilanguage support of query string

Tags: jsp, url, internationalization, urlencode, atg

I have some japanese text in query string in URL.
Which is 個人情報保護方針

But when I am trying to render that using  tag.It is displaying below text.

åäººæå ±ä¿è­·æ¹é.
How to handle this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101823/extract-chinese-text-from-query-string

Comment: @Suresh How this can be achieved in j2ee application.